# SQLite query not working with concatenated string

Tags: java, android, string, sqlite, android-sqlite

Here is the code of my android app where I use SQLite:

```
String wordInQuotes = "\"" + inputWord + "\"";
String query = "select * from table where col = " +wordInQuotes + ";";
Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(query, null);
```

This gives me no results. Whereas if I remove the concatenation,

```
 String query = "select * from table where col = \"apple\" ;";
```

it works perfectly. So how do I write a query where I can replace the column value dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String query = "select * from table where col = \""+value+"\" ";
```

Comment: Did you check if the value that you specified, is actually available?

Comment: And did you remove the ';' as I did in my first answer? In the update it cam back without notice and this would cause a problem.

Answer (score 2):

Try this it will work

for exact input

```
String query = "select * from table where col = '" +inputword + "'";
```

for input start from end

```
String query = "select * from table where col = '" +inputword + "%'";
```

for input start from starting point

```
String query = "select * from table where col = '%" +inputword + "'";
```

for input contains any where in column

```
String query = "select * from table where col = '%" +inputword + "%'";
```

execute query

```
Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(query, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String query = "select * from table where col ='" +inputWord + "'";
```